# how to call operation queue?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

Trying to parse a Json file from ClassA and get the results in ClassB.

ClassB invokes getResultfromA() method on ViewDidLoad(); which gets the parsed result from ClassA and then are displayed in the label view that are associated with ClassB

**Problem part**:-  the results gets printed as nil in ClassB, but after a sec or so the parsed results are printed in ClassA,

**Conclusion**:- from what i understand i am doing something stupid in async task, which is supposed to make the task in ClassB wait till data is received from ClassA, which is what the desired end result should be

```
  ClassA () {

    func getJsonBookDetails(isbnString:String) -> Dictionary<String, String>{

    var gBooks = Dictionary<String, String>()
    let scriptUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:" + isbnString

    let myurl = URL(string:scriptUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myurl!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myurl! ) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print("THIS ERROR",error!)
        return
        } else{
        if let mydata = data{
            do{
                let myJson = try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mydata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as AnyObject

                if let dictonary = myJson["items"] as? NSArray {
                --/* parsed results stored in dictionary gBooks*/---                       
               }
                /* trying to send dictionary gBooks to  ClassB */
                var  myVar = ClassB()                  
                OperationQueue.addOperation() 
               /*  */
              } catch{
                print("Error found")
            }
           }      
        }
    }
task.resume()    
return gBooks
   }
}
```

This is for ClassB where, the results are to the displayed

```
 ClassB {
       var userGbook = [String:String]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getResultfromB()
       }

 func getResultfromA(){
    /* call func getJsonBookDetails() from classA and store in 
    userGbook /*
   /* display the result stored in associated labels using the keys form the dictionary */ 
    }
 }
```

Comment: search for `completion handler` and `delegate pattern` on SO or google

Comment: You've got the code that should be passing the data to your ClassB object inside the completion handler for the data task, which is right. Explain what you expect to happen? It sounds like `ClassB` is a view controller? Do you want to wait until the data is loaded, then push a new view controller of type `ClassB` onto your navigation stack or present it modally, and display the data there?

Comment: (Your use of an operation queue doesn't make any sense, and neither does the way you create an instance of `ClassB` in your completion handler and then don't do anything with it.)

Comment: @DuncanC the instance of the class is just a try; the senario is when classB UIView is loaded using the onload method, the parsed JSON from classA is to be presented in ClassB. I have updated the method name in classB